# R Recompiling documentation & package unload results in lazy-load error

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

I'm using `Roxygen2` to document my R (3.2.4) package and have several windows open as I fix my function `@examples`:

1) R session where I type `devtools::document()` to update the `Rd` file

2) terminal window where I reinstall the package with the updated doc using
`R CMD INSTALL myPackage`

3) R session where I unload/reload the package and look at the updated documentation:

```
> detach(package:myPackage,unload=TRUE);require(myPackage)
> ?myTestFunc
```

The problem is in window 3. After running the `detach()` and `require()`, typing `?myTestFunc` gives me the following error:

```
Error in fetch(key) : 
  lazy-load database     '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/netDx/help/myTestFunc.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In fetch(key) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Restarting R allows me to run `?myTestFunc` and see the updated documentation. 
How do I unload and reload the package "completely" without having to start R each time?

Thanks for your time!

PS - some output from `sessionInfo()`, incase it helps.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
```

Comment: Do you use RStudio? Because RStudio has build in tools to make building your own package very comfortable!

Comment: Hi J_F, I first tried this workflow with window 3 in RStudio. Got this error and so switched to using command-line R. Didn't help, so here I am. If you could suggest a tutorial to achieve documentation update/package reinstall/example rerun in Rstudio that would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486508-Building-Testing-and-Distributing-Packages

My approach is the following one:
(1) change your code
(2) devtools::document(".")
(3) CTRL + SHIFT + B to "Build & Reload" the package